# Is lattice-based cryptography relevant in symmetric cryptography?

Tags: symmetric, lattice-crypto

I've seen that lattice-based cryptography works well with public key cryptography as well as cryptographic hashing algorithms, but does it apply to symmetric key cryptography?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, it is not**, assuming you are talking about symmetric ciphers, pseudorandom generators, and hash algorithms.<sup>*</sup> Symmetric cryptography does not need to use any mathematical hardness problem to be secure, and there is no need to have a security reduction to one. It is technically possible to design a symmetric algorithm out of a core construct that is normally used for asymmetric cryptography, as in the very slow Blum Blum Shub or the backdoored Dual_EC_DRBG pseudorandom generators, but that's rare. Such constructions have no real advantages over typical symmetric ones.

Note that you do not need dedicated post-quantum cryptography to protect your symmetric encryption keys. The quantum Grover's algorithm does not hit symmetric cryptography nearly as hard as Shor's algorithm hits asymmetric cryptography. Even with extremely high-speed and low-latency quantum computers, it would suffice to double your key length from 128 to 256 to remain safe.

<sub>* If you consider homomorphic encryption to be symmetric, then the answer might very well be yes.</sub>

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the answer is no, but I'm not certain to the last fraction of percentage.

Lattice-based cryptography are usually linear, and are based on linear hard problems such as "learning with error", and "short integer solution", etc.

Symmetric-key primitives such as block cipher, needs to defend against linear analysis, so lattices have little application here other than it may be useful for providing diffusion.

I assume you mean SWIFFT when you mentioned "hash function". As for that, I've a [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/71243/36960) regarding its suitability in HKDF (HMAC-based key derivation function) you might be interested in.

Comment: I checked out your question, its a shame that we have to finagle so much with post-quantum cryptography in order to get the cryptographic primitives we want. Se la vie.